# Result mismatch between elem match, and greater than and less than in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56df07927a65825b47d5e77d"),
    "internal_id" : 67627,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-12-14T16:10:11.015Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-16T12:40:57.328Z"),
    "name" : "DPA_Top Brands",
    "company_id" : 2,
    "ad_account_id" : 15,
    "created_time" : ISODate("2015-12-14T15:51:47.000Z"),
    "daily" : [ 
        {
            "fb_impressions" : 1335,
            "fb_clicks" : 93,
            "fb_spend" : 1098.3499999999999091,
            "timestamp" : "2015-12-16"
        }, 
        {
            "fb_impressions" : 5072,
            "fb_clicks" : 475,
            "timestamp" : "2016-01-19"
        }, 
        {
            "fb_impressions" : 322,
            "fb_clicks" : 37,
            "timestamp" : "2016-01-16"
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not return the above document

```
db.getCollection('ads').find({'ad_account_id': 15, 'daily': {'$elemMatch': {'timestamp': {'$lte': '2016-01-15', '$gte': '2016-01-01'}}}})
```

But this returns the above document

```
db.getCollection('ads').find({'ad_account_id': 15, 'daily.timestamp': {'$lte': '2016-01-15', '$gte': '2016-01-01'}})
```

**The above query is clearly incorrect, and should not return data as no data is between the two dates.**

I believe its the timestamp with '2015' which is really messing up things, but I don't get why. Why is the result of the two different? The elem-match is clearly correct.

Attached output

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: test

```
> db.getCollection('ads').find({'ad_account_id': 15, 'daily.timestamp': {'$lte': '2016-01-15', '$gte': '2016-01-01'}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56df07927a65825b47d5e77d"), "internal_id" : 67627, "created_at" : ISODate("2015-12-14T16:10:11.015Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-16T12:40:57.328Z"), "name" : "DPA_Top Brands", "company_id" : 2, "ad_account_id" : 15, "created_time" : ISODate("2015-12-14T15:51:47Z"), "daily" : [ { "fb_impressions" : 1335, "fb_clicks" : 93, "fb_spend" : 1098.35, "timestamp" : "2015-12-16" }, { "fb_impressions" : 5072, "fb_clicks" : 475, "timestamp" : "2016-01-19" }, { "fb_impressions" : 322, "fb_clicks" : 37, "timestamp" : "2016-01-16" } ] }
> db.getCollection('ads').find({'ad_account_id': 15, 'daily': {'$elemMatch': {'timestamp': {'$lte': '2016-01-15', '$gte': '2016-01-01'}}}})
>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally none of the queries should return anything: the three dates are outside the date range. However, I tried the queries with the range 2016-01-01 -> 2016-01-20 and the two work identically for me: they return the document.

Comment: @dgiugg - Only the second one returns the document, the first one doesn't.

Comment: Ok sorry. Actually it seems that in the second query it "unwinds" the query, like in the example [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#array-match-embedded-documents). It is not exactly the same case but the behaviour is the same, the query will be the same as `db.getCollection('ads').find({'ad_account_id': 15, 'daily.timestamp': {'$lte': '2016-01-15'}, 'daily.timestamp': {'$gte': '2016-01-01'}})`, so **the two criteria can be satisfied by two different elements of the array**.

Comment: @dgiugg Makes a lot of sense...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the date comparision.

You cannot use find with multiple query conditions to search a nested array of documents ideal way is to use $query. 'daily' is an array is daily.timestamp is not valid. However you can use 'daily.0.timestamp' to get the correct value. When you are using find with multiple conditions, if any of the conditions are met it will return you the document.